# How to clear php form after submission

Tags: php, contact-form

I am trying to clear up the form after submission. I am not sure what I am missing. I will attach the PHP code below. This is my first time coding a contact form or anything using PHP, so try to bear with me. Thank you guys in advance!

Sorry thought I had attached the code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EMAIL AND SUBJECT
    $email_to = "##@##.com";

    $email_subject = "New form submission";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "<span style='color: red;' /><center> We're sorry, but there's errors found with the form you submitted.<br /><br /></center></span>";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo '<span style="color: red;" /><center>Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br /></center></span>';
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.</center></span>');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $message = $_POST['message']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= '<span style="color: red;" /><center>The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br /></center></span>';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[0-9.-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$telephone) > 10) {
    $error_message .= '<span style="color: red;" /><center>The Telephone number you entered does not appear to be valid.<br /></center></span>';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= '<span style="color: red;" /><center>The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br /></center></span>';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= '<span style="color: red;" /><center>The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br /></center></span>';
  }
  if(strlen($message) < 10) {
    $error_message .= '<span style="color: red;" /><center>The Message you typed seems to be too short, add more words, please.</center></span><br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- The success html below -->
<span style="color: green;"><center>Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.</center></span>

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Comment: *I will attach the PHP code below.* So where is it?

Comment: Please edit the question and add the PHP code.

Comment: you could use javascript [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2Fform.reset)

Comment: I really need to see some code so i can determine how the data is being persisted.

Comment: One method that you can use is: `header("Location: success_file.php");` once the form has been successfully sent. That way, they won't be able to click back, unless you give them the option to. You can use `if` conditions as well.

Comment: If you want to go about this method, you can replace `<span style="color: green;"><center>Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.</center></span>` with `header("Location: success_file.php");` and have that code set inside that file (success_file.php). That way, they won't be able to use the back button to access your form. It works for me. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Or you can also use an Ajax/jQuery method, but that's a whole new ball of wax.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Fred. The thing is, I am using iframe, so the `<span style="color: green;"><center>Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.</center></span>` will show up under the form after it has been submitted

Comment: @RyanAbi You're quite welcome. Ah, I didn't notice an `iframe` code in your question. That's a whole different ball game. Details as such should be included in questions, as it tends to complicate things. Is the use of an `iframe` that important? You can also use Ajax/jQuery to do the same effect. Using my suggestion for `header` will most probably throw off an error of `headers already sent`, pretty sure, so can't use that.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that I am using an iframe /: But yea, I want the person submitting the form to stay on the page. Maybe I can use javascript?

Comment: @RyanAbi No problemo. Ajax and jQuery, yes. Ajax uses JS, and that would be the route to go. However, you may still be able to use your existing code, and display your success message set inside a `<div>` instead. But Ajax would definitely be the way to go.

Comment: @RyanAbi Here's a nice script and demo http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/ and you can also Google "ajax jquery forms php" which is what I did just now. I'm almost tempted to use that script myself! lol It will need some slight modifications to make sure a valid Email was entered, but other than that, it works beautifully.

Comment: @Fred thank you so much for taking the time to help me out! I really appreciate all the help!

Comment: @RyanAbi You're very much welcome Ryan, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is reload the form like you did originally.  I generally create a function that displays the form.  When the first part of the script detects whether the form was submitted.  If it was not, then you display the form.  If it was, then you process the input THEN display the form.

Here's some pseudo-ish code to help out.

```
<?php
  function display_form () {
    // display your form here
    // For my sample, I assume a clear button and a submit button
  }

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Submit button was clicked

    // put your form processing code here

  } else { // Form was not submitted or 'clear' was clicked

    display_form();

  }
?>
```

Comment: For the moment and without seeing the OP's code, we can't tell for sure if reloading the page won't clear out the information already inserted. For instance; Firefox (v22 is what I use). I have seen forms that would retain the information already inserted into their respective fields even after reloading the page. If your method pans out, then you should post some code. Answers such as this, are better off said as a comment.

Comment: @Fred Lee can't comment yet

Comment: @DevZer0 Yes, I know ;-) with an answer as such, one would think that including sample code to back it up (Lee's theory), and stand to be beneficial for the OP.

Comment: I can comment!  I didn't think code would be necessary since I didn't have the OP's code to work from.  I didn't want to post unfamiliar code that might confuse the issue.  I will edit my answer to include some pseudo-type code to clarify.

Comment: Also, I've never encountered a browser that automatically re-inserted the form data...

Answer (score 1):

You could have one page with the form and all the information, like contact.php, but submit the data through the form to another page, like,

Then on process_page.php, once you have processed the data, redirect the user back to the original page with query string attached to it, like

`header('Location: contact.php?status=mail%20sent%20successfully');`

and display the query string through `echo $_GET['status']` or create alternative message / layout based on that status. Don't forget to handle cases where $_GET is set, but empty, too!

This is a bit nicer, because it separates your processing logic from the interactive part of the website.